# HTTP 2.0 linux: differentiating streams implies 65K buffer?

Tags: http, unix, recv

I was having a look at the [HTTP2 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-04#section-4) and I see that :

- it has multi-streams per connection,
- each stream has an id,
- and the max size of a payload is 65K

That means that the recv buffer should be at least 65K in order not to mix up the streams, is it right ? Isn't that a little heavy ?

Comment: TCP/IP (frames/buffers) are below HTTP (frames/buffers) which are below usage of streaming data.

Comment: And ? When recv()'ing, if my buffer is less than 65K and I get a frame longer than my buffer, how do I know which stream is it ?

Comment: TCP provides a stream (of frames), the HTTP streams are frames on top of this, and the HTTP streaming on top yet. By examining the first few bytes in the HTTP stream frame you can tell how long the stream is and loop around reading data as appropriate. TCP won't mess up the underlying TCP stream order (that is, the HTTP stream frames won't be "mixed" at the application, even if read across multiple calls or "buffer loads") so you'll eventually get all the data from recv, even with much smaller buffers.

Comment: The buffer size with recv does *not* correlate directly with read HTTP stream frames - you'll still have to handle HTTP stream frame over/underflow from any buffers read. Imagine if there was a 65k buffer, but the HTTP frames were 32k, 65k, .. at the 2nd frame there is already a "split" across buffer.

Comment: My question is when the buffer is smaller than the frames. How do you correlate in that case ? With epoll API all I have is the connection fd.

Comment: You simply keep reading from recv until you've read as much as you want to read. Say the recv buffer is 65k. This effictively means that 0..65k of data will be immediately available to read. However, 0..65k of data can be read (i.e. not always the maximum size), with *no* guarantee of alignment over the higher-level protocol. It's the job of the (HTTP) application to reconstitute any HTTP frames/streams. Most of the HTTP payload (in both directions) can be treated as a stream when reconstituted and processed even before the HTTP frame (or stream for such a frame) completes.